# in (R) S3, what is the use of function.class.class?

Tags: r

In S3 style OOP, a function name written as `foo.A` is used for calling method **foo** for class **A** .
But recently I came across function written  as `function.class.class`

```
foo.A.B <- function(x){
##---
}
```

What is this kind of function do?

Comment: Can you name the actual function (and if it's in a package, which package)?

Comment: here is an example: https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/master/R/fortify_MSwM.R

Comment: It's a little confusing, but I believe the S3 class in that case is actually `MSM.lm`. I'd have to go check the details in the docs, but I suspect S3 treats everything after the first `.` as the object class. For example, otherwise it would be confused by `function.data.frame`.

Comment: That make sense. Coming from Python background the '.' makes things little confusing. I thought in 'foo.A.B' makes 'foo' method for class B where class B must be inherited from class 'A' . I guess I am interpenetrating '.'

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is *terrible*, and people who do this should be shot (er, I mean, strongly reprimanded). The rule in R is simple: the dot is reserved for S3, use underscore (`_`) to separate words in your function or class names instead. And use consistent capitalisation. Bad: `fortify.MSM.lm`. Good: `fortify.msm_lm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Posting as answer to close out the question)

As @joran pointed out, the function `fortify.MSM.lm` is actually just a method for the `fortify` function for an object of type `MSM.lm`. There is no implied heirachy from the use of the period here. The period in R in most cases is just like any other character for naming variables; it does not have the same significance it does in other languages. One of the few exceptions is, as you've already see, naming methods for S3 generic functions.

So you could define

```
my.fun <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("my.fun")
my.fun.data.frame <- function(x, ...) summary(x)
my.fun(mtcars)
```

So in the name `my.fun.data.frame`. The periods don't mean anything, it's just that when you call `my.fun` with a class of `data.frame`, R will look for a function called `"my.fun" + "." + "data.frame"`.